# How can I prevent R from extrapolating the regression line outside the range of data points using a mixed model?

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, mixed-models, marginal-effects

I am fitting a mixed model in R with an interaction term as follows: `model <- lmer(y ~ x * z + (1|h), data = df)`. `y` and `x` are continuous variables and `z` is a categorical variable, and `h` is a random effect.

Data:

```
 n <- 50
df <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(n),
  z = sample(-1:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  h = sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), # random effect
  y = z*(0.5*x) + rnorm(n,0,0.2))
df$z <- as.factor(df$z)
df$h <- as.factor(df$h)
```

Then, I'm using the `plot_predictions()` function from the `marginaleffects` package, then I use `facet_wrap(~ z)` from the `ggplot2` to visualize each regression separately of the different categories as follows:

```
plot_predictions(model, condition = c("x","z"), vcov = T, points= 0.3) + facet_wrap(~ z)
```

As you can notice the first and second plots extrapolate the regression line outside the range of their data according to the limits of data points of the third plot.

So, I try to control this by adding `newdata = df`:

```
plot_predictions(model, new data = df, by = c("x","z"), vcov = T, points= 0.3) + facet_wrap(~ z)
```

however, now I have a new problem; I lose the linear effect and it looks like a disruptive non-continuous line. Interestingly, it only happens when I fit a mixed model with random effects (i.e., glmm, hgam) but this is not the case for a simple linear model.

[See plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjePq.png)

Any idea how I can prevent this from happening, constraining my regression line (+- CIs) to the range of the data points for each panel and keeping the linear model line?

Comment: Hey JaGo, if you post the rest of your code (e.g., instead of saying "Then I'm using `plot_predictions`...", actually post the rest of your code, you'll get more help. Include the libraries too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below seems to work as expected using the latest version of `marginaleffects`.

(PS: Next time, it would be convenient for people who try to give answers if you wrote a complete replicable example with libraries and a continuous code block that we can jut cut and paste.)

```r
library(lme4)
library(ggplot2)
library(marginaleffects)
n <- 50
df <- tibble::tibble(
  x = rnorm(n),
  z = sample(-1:1, n, replace = TRUE),
  h = sample(1:3, n, replace=TRUE), # random effect
  y = z*(0.5*x) + rnorm(n,0,0.2))
df$z <- as.factor(df$z)
df$h <- as.factor(df$h)
model <- lmer(y ~ x * z + (1|h), data = df)

plot_predictions(model, newdata = df, by = c("x","z"), vcov = TRUE, points= 0.3) +
    facet_wrap(~ z, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Vincent, thanks for your answer and for your amazing package. I already updated the `marginaleffects` package with the latest version `0.15.1`, however, my problem remains the same "I lose the linear effect and it shows a disruptive non-continuous line instead". I'm using the same code and it doesn't work. Now you can see an image of this in my original post.  Not sure why it is happening.

Comment: Right, this sometimes happens when using `by` instead of `condition`. This is normal and "correct", because the quantities computed are different (see the plotting vignette on the website). Unfortunately, there is no way to constrain the axes in individual facets automatically using the `condition` argument. The easiest solution is to set `draw=FALSE`, which will return a data frame. You can then subset the data frame as you want, and use `ggplot2` to plot the results.